# Bootstrap Carousel working in Bootply, not in browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

So everything appears to be working when I load up the html on bootply, but when I push it to my webpage (Github page) the carousel loads, but doesn't do any scrolling.

Heres the HTML I have pushed to the site, its exactly the same on Bootply except for the addition of the script near the top, which I read was needed to make it work, but it doesnt seem to do anything. It wasnt necessary on the Bootply apparently.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('#carousel-content').carousel();
    });
    </script>

<body>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <div class="nav">
      <p><br><br></p>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="potrait">
        <p><br><br></p>
        <img src = "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-eQB0B8kGRiw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/gRPFLBygtI8/photo.jpg" class="center-block img-circle" height="200" width="200">
    </div>

    <div class="info">
        <p><br><br></p>
        <h1 class="text-center"> Matt Kowalczykowski </h1>
        <h2 class="text-center"> Mechatronics Engineering Student </h2>
        <p><br><br></p>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-centered">
                <div id="carousel-content" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <!-- Indicators -->
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-content" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-content" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-content" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  </ol>

                  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                      <img src="http://images.wisegeek.com/robots-assembling-car-bodies.jpg">
                      <div class="carousel-caption">
                          <h3>Mechanical</h3>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                      <img src="http://seetech-corp.com/engineering/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/seetech-electrical-engineering-cabinets.jpg">
                      <div class="carousel-caption">
                          <h3>Electrical</h3>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                      <img src="http://cdn.onextrapixel.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/clean-coding-best-practices.jpg">
                      <div class="carousel-caption">
                          <h3>Programming</h3>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <!-- Controls -->
                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-content" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-content" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                  </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that top JavaScript, but you do need to load the Bootstrap Javascript files. Preferably right before the

```
</body>
```

tag.

```
<script src="link/to/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

For you I think it would be dist/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: This looks right and that is where my js files are - but it still isnt working any ideas?

Comment: Heres a JFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b74fzmc3/, which doesnt work, and a bootply which does http://www.bootply.com/JfZZaUYBAx

Answer (score 0):

You're not including bootstrap.js.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```